# Observable.merge and debounce in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, debouncing

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import io.reactivex.Observable;

public class SampleRx {

    Observable<String> getBoth() {
        return Observable.merge(getSeq1(), getSeq2());
    }

    Observable<String> getSeq1() {
        return Observable.create(emitter -> {
            emitter.onNext("A");

            Thread.sleep(1_500);
            emitter.onNext("B");

            Thread.sleep(500);
            emitter.onNext("C");

            Thread.sleep(250);
            emitter.onNext("D");

            Thread.sleep(2_000);
            emitter.onNext("E");
            // Thread.sleep(2_000);
            emitter.onComplete();
        });
    }

    Observable<String> getSeq2() {
        return Observable.create(emitter -> {
            Thread.sleep(200);
            emitter.onNext("1");

            Thread.sleep(500);
            emitter.onNext("2");

            Thread.sleep(400);
            emitter.onNext("3");

            Thread.sleep(300);
            emitter.onNext("4");

            Thread.sleep(1_800);
            emitter.onNext("5");
            emitter.onComplete();
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
val=A
val=D
val=4
val=5
```

Why is there `5` whereas `E` is ignored (because it's followed by `onComplete()` as I guess).

Comment: What does the value `2_000` mean in `Thread.sleep(2_000);`?

Comment: it should be millisecond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your code :

`SampleRx().getBoth().subscribe(System.out::println);`

I get :

```
A
B 
C 
D 
E 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

This is correct behaviour, results will not be interleaved as this uses the calling/same thread for all emissions, and the `merge` only completes when both Obervables signal completed.

To achieve interleaving for the merge each `Observable` need to run on a different thread, so they do not block one another, so if each observable is subscribed to on `io` i.e.

```
Observable.<String>create(emitter -> {
            emitter.onNext(value);
            ...
            ...
            emitter.onComplete();
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Then you get this output :

```
A, Thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
1, Thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
2, Thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
3, Thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
4, Thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
B, Thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
C, Thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
D, Thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
5, Thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
E, Thread : RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
```

Which then honours independent emissions that do not block each other.

You have not provided any information regarding a debounce, which you included in your title, so I cannot comment.